# Autofill an Input based on another input

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I'm trying to add a quick conditional logic to my Laravel project. If a "create_copay" text input is anything other than 0.00, my "create_ams_fee" field should display 0.00. Else, it will be 7.00. However, my code displays no change whatsoever in the create_ams_fee field.

**Form Fields (Laravel Collective)**

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('copay', 'Copay')}}
    {{Form::text('copay', '', ['class' => $errors->has('copay') ? 'form-control border border-danger' : 'form-control', 'id' => 'create_copay'])}}
</div><!-- /form-group -->
<div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('ams_fee', 'AMS Fee')}}
    {{Form::text('ams_fee', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'create_ams_fee'])}}
</div><!-- /form-group -->
```

**Script**

```
// Calculate AMS Fee field
$('#create_copay').change(function() {
    if ($('#create_copay').val() == '0.00') {
        $('#create_ams_fee').val('7.00');
    } else {
        $('#create_ams_fee').val('0.00');
    };
});
```

**Edit**

This seems to be turning into a dynamic loading issue. The codeblock below is what I'm resulting to try and test. The parent container of these inputs has an id of `create_financials`. I currently am having no success finding a way to trigger an event by changing the `create_copay` field.

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $('#create_financials').on('input', '#create_copay', function() {
        console.log('SUCCESS');
    });
});
```

Comment: How is `create_copay` input element value modified? I ask, because changing the value programmatically will not fire the `change` event.

Comment: @RandyCasburn it is done through manual entry. Though, I may also have a situation on an edit page where it will already exist and may need to be calculated.

Comment: use `blur` event instead of `change`

Comment: Are you creating the form fields dynamically? Add `console.log('in')` inside the js block to verify if it's running. If not, and you are creating it dynamically , then you'll need to access it as `$(document).change('#create_copay', function(){...}`. Instead of `document` try to use closest parent element which was not created dynamically.

Comment: @brnd0 - I'll answer for the OP, Yes, Laravel (PHP) is dynamically creating these elements on the fly server side.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the 'change' event - this is only fired when focus is taken out of the element (it is blurred) and it has changed, or the form is submitted, or certain other times.

You could use the keydown or keyup events, but a better one is the 'input' event.

If this is a number input, you should use the input type 'number' rather than text - however, if you don't want to or can't do that, casting the text from the input to a number might also be beneficial:

```
$('#create_copay').on('input', function() {
    if ($('#create_copay').val()/1 == 0) {
        $('#create_ams_fee').val('7.00');
    } else {
        $('#create_ams_fee').val('0.00');
    };
});
```

Please see this codepen for a working example:

https://codepen.io/manticorp/pen/wYpXWY

Using the html inspector (right click, inspect element) are you sure your inputs have the ids specified? (create_copay and create_ams_fee).

Also, I've just seen your inputs may already be populated, in which case something like this would be better:

```
$(function() { // jQuery domready event

    $('#create_copay').on('input', updateFields);
    function updateFields() {
        if ($('#create_copay').val()/1 == 0) {
            $('#create_ams_fee').val('7.00');
        } else {
            $('#create_ams_fee').val('0.00');
        };
    }
    updateFields();
});
```

If you are creating these fields dynamically, or inserting them into the document after load somehow, then you will need to attach the event to the document/a container element:

```
$(function() { // jQuery domready event
    $('#theContainer').on('input', '#create_copay', updateFields);
    function updateFields() {
        if ($('#create_copay').val()/1 == 0) {
            $('#create_ams_fee').val('7.00');
        } else {
            $('#create_ams_fee').val('0.00');
        };
    }
    updateFields();
});
```

Comment: This brings no change for me, unfortunately. On element inspection, I get a return of: <input class="form-control" id="create_copay" name="copay" type="text" value> == $0

Answer (score -1):

Use the `keydown` event for input field. `Change` takes effect after the input element loses focus.

Comment: I have replaced the change event with keydown/keyup/keypress and the create_ams_fee field remains blank.